# Why does Ruby's String#to_i sometimes return 0 when the string contains a number?

Tags: ruby, string, data-conversion

I was just trying out Ruby and I came across `String#to_i`. Suppose I have this code:

```
var1 = '6 sldasdhkjas'
var2 = 'aljdfldjlfjldsfjl 6'
```

Why does `puts var1.to_i` output `6` when `puts var2.to_i` gives `0`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `to_i` method returns the number that is formed by all parseable digits *at the start* of a string. Your first string starts with a with digit so `to_i` returns that, the second string doesn't start with a digit so 0 is returned. BTW, whitespace is ignored, so `" 123abc".to_i` returns 123.

Comment: So that means if there is non-integer character in the beginning of the string, to_i will ignore the rest of the string ?

Comment: Exactly, if the string starts with a non-integer character it immediately stops parsing and returns 0, ignoring any numbers that might come later in the string.

Comment: That isn't completely true - it will parse through whitespace characters.  " 123".to_i will evaluate to 123, as would a string beginning with a tab.

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation for [`String#to_i`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i):

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an integer

Answer (score 6):

More exhaustive examples of `to_i`:

```
irb(main):013:0* "a".to_i
=> 0
irb(main):014:0> "".to_i
=> 0
irb(main):015:0> nil.to_i
=> 0
irb(main):016:0> "2014".to_i
=> 2014
irb(main):017:0> "abc2014".to_i
=> 0
irb(main):018:0> "2014abc".to_i
=> 2014
irb(main):019:0> " 2014abc".to_i
=> 2014
```