# If type is character I want to puts error

Tags: ruby, types, char, sum

```
puts "Let's sum many numbers"

sum = 0
num = 0
while(num != 'x')
  puts "Press a number and then Enter if you exit press 'x'"
  num = gets.chomp
  if num != 'x'
    num = num.to_i 
    print "#{sum} + #{num} = "
    sum += num
    puts "#{sum}"
  elsif num == 'x'
    puts "Total sum is #{sum}"
    break
  else 
    puts "error!"
  end
 end
```

I want to make code to show error If user press char except 'x'.
How should I do?

Comment: What language is this? What currently goes wrong with it?

Comment: You might want to edit your post to add a tag which names whatever language this is supposed to be.

Comment: This is Ruby language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768865/regarding-to-i-method-of-ruby

Answer (score -1):

Change your first `if` to a condition that checks if the input is a number, e.g.

```
if num =~ /\A[0..9]+\z/   # or /\A\d+\z/
```

The way your code is currently, all strings except `'x'` are treated as number -- with value `0` in case they aren't really numbers:

```
'foobar'.to_i  # => 0
```