# Rails: Issue with turning "0000221" (string) into 221 (integer)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
  inventory_amount = columns[17] # returns a string "0000221"
  puts "inventory_amount = #{inventory_amount}"
  hello = inventory_amount.to_i
  puts "hello = #{hello}"
```

But this is spitting out:

```
  inventory_amount = "0000221"
  hello = 0
```

What is going on? In my console it works:

```
    1.9.3p362 :033 > w = "0000019"
     => "0000019" 
    1.9.3p362 :034 > w.to_i
     => 19
```

I'm using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.3

=== Update===

Could it be because It's coming from a file??

```
File.open(file).each_line do |line|
  columns = line.split(",")
  isbn = columns[0]
  inventory_amount = columns[17].to_i
  puts "inventory_amount = #{inventory_amount}" #this still doesn't work
```

Yes I'm sure columns[17] is a string:

```
  inventory_amount = columns[17]
  puts "inventory_amount = #{inventory_amount.class}"
```

Prints this:

```
inventory_amount = String
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768865/regarding-to-i-method-of-ruby

Comment: Try printing out `columns[17].length` and or `columns[17].inspect`.

Comment: Per the link from @BradWerth, there's likely some non-numeric (non-printable) character in the string before you get to the `2`.

Comment: Yeh I think you got it @PeterAlfvin . It printed out `columns[17] = 9
columns[17] = "\"0000221\""` Thanks!

Comment: :-) We should have caught that based on the `"` in the generated output!

Comment: Can you please submit that as the answer, and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
inventory_amount = columns[17].to_i
```

That way there aren't any other conversions happening first.