# String to integer explicit conversion

Tags: ruby

I have the following piece of code:

```
gets().to_i
```

When I input `"A"`, `"a"`, `"world"`, or anything and convert it to an integer using `to_i`, I get `0` returned. Can anybody explain what is going on here and why I see `0` always?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768865/regarding-to-i-method-of-ruby

Answer (score 2):

That's because a string converted to integer returns `0` or an integer if the string starts with digits.

```
➜  ~  irb
2.1.5 :001 > "whatever".to_i
 => 0
2.1.5 :002 > "12-whatever".to_i
 => 12
2.1.5 :003 > "whatever-12".to_i
 => 0
```

As you are trying to convert `A`, `a`, `world` to integer (which doesn't make sense), you'll get `0`.

You should check whether the input is an integer, before trying to cast it to integer. You can either use a regular expression, or the `Integer` method that will raise if the input is not an integer.

```
2.1.5 :004 > Integer(12)
 => 12
2.1.5 :005 > Integer("world")
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "world"
    from (irb):5:in `Integer'
    from (irb):5
    from /Users/weppos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.5 :006 > Integer("12-world")
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "12-world"
    from (irb):6:in `Integer'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/weppos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) on this is well written.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you describe cannot be reproduced. In all of the particular examples you gave, `String#to_i` indeed returns `0`, but that does not mean that it returns `0` for any string. First, `to_i` sees if the beginning of the string can be interpreted as an integer. If so, it returns that integer. If not, it returns `0`.